# Rails, get circledByCount with omniauth-google-oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-authentication

I use omniauth-google-oauth2 gem and want to get all people in my circle on google plus account, my omniauth file:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, ENV['twitter_key'], ENV['twitter_secret'], info_fields: 'followers_count'
  provider :instagram, ENV['instagram_key'], ENV['instagram_secret'], info_fields: 'follows'
  provider :facebook, ENV['facebook_key'], ENV['facebook_secret'], info_fields: 'friends'
  google_scope = "plus.login"

  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['google_key'], ENV['google_secret'], scope: google_scope, access_type: "offline"
end
```

but request.env['omniauth.auth'] return:

```
"id_info"=>
{"iss"=>"accounts.google.com",
 "at_hash"=>"secret",
 "aud"=>"secret",
 "sub"=>"secret",
 "azp"=>"secret",
 "iat"=>1445275484,
 "exp"=>1445279084},
"raw_info"=>
{"kind"=>"plus#personOpenIdConnect",
 "gender"=>"male",
 "sub"=>"103458288129240855409",
 "name"=>"Sergey Naumenko",
 "given_name"=>"Sergey",
 "family_name"=>"Naumenko",
 "profile"=>"https://plus.google.com/103458288129240855409",
 "picture"=>"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-b8p4jlJRIm8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAV4/rZXezwwCy7w/photo.jpg?sz=50",
 "locale"=>"en"}}}
```

I need get circledByCount

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with adding option skip_friends: false

```
provider :google_oauth2, ENV['google_key'], ENV['google_secret'], scope: google_scope, skip_friends: false
```